# IMG with position absolute invisible in Firefox while showing in IE, Chrome, Safari - why?

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

The element with class `slide` in the following shall keep a fixed aspect ratio controlled by the `padding-bottom:44%;` in the CSS. Elements inside (images with class `slide`) shall be cropped to fit the box while scaled to 100% width.

Now my problem is that this works fine in Chrome, Safari, even IE but in Firefox it just won't show at all. Why is that?

My HTML:

```
<header class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide" src="https://cranmoremtlodge.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/fall-foliage-003.jpg" />
        </div>
</header>
```

My CSS:

```
/*these two are mine*/
.swiper-slide {
  width: 1664px; /*assigned as element style by swiper*/
    position:relative;
  padding-bottom:44%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.swiper-slide .slide {
  position:absolute;
  top:-50%; bottom:-50%;
  margin:auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: teal;
}

/*these three come with www.idangero.us/swiper/ */
.swiper-wrapper {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition-property: transform;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.swiper-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.swiper-slide {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/smauo1wu/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot going on in your code, and some of it is causing problems.

For instance, you're not adhering to the [**CSS rule for percentage heights**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276). Also, your absolute positioning in `.swiper-slide .slide` doesn't appear to be necessary and is pushing your image off-screen on re-size (when other issues are resolved).

Anyway, here's some revised code that may help you. The image now appears and scales in all browsers (tested in Chrome, FF and IE11).

**HTML** (no changes)

**Revised CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; } /* NEW */

.swiper-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%; /* NEW */
}

.swiper-wrapper {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition-property: transform;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: 1664px;
    position:relative;
  padding-bottom:44%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%; /* NEW */
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide .slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: teal;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/smauo1wu/7/)